# CKEditor lost content when sorting

Tags: jquery-ui, ckeditor, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 ckeditors in the same container (a div) like below (textarea will be replaced by my js code with ckeditor):

```
<div id="container">
    <textarea id="cke0"></textarea>
    <textarea id="cke1"></textarea>
</div>
```

It's works great, but I have an issue when I let the container div be sortable (with jquery ui sortable) like :

```
$("#container").sortable();
```

I lost the content of the editor and the editor is no more editable and accessible. I can't focus the editor. I check in the debugger and the editor (the iframe) is still present in the DOM.

Anyone had this issue ?

thanks for replies
Bastien

Comment: I'm not privy to the specifics of what is happening here, but you may have to re-initialize the CKEditor after the dragging & dropping. Not sure, I guess we'll see

Comment: I found the answer on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379653/ckeditor-freezes-on-jquery-ui-reorder

Answer (score 4):

I used extra plugin 'divarea' (it replaces iframe by div) and 'cancel' options in sortable.

Something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('cke0',{extraPlugins: 'divarea'});

$('#container').sortable({items: 'textarea',cancel: '.cke_inner'});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The `cancel` option was my missing piece. Now I finally can remove all my "restore CKEditor if dragged"-JavaScript code that's been haunting me for years.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! ( the 'items' part is not necessary, and don't forget to install divarea first, maybe with CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'divarea', '/my-js-folder/ckeditor_plugins/divarea/', 'plugin.js' ); if you use a CDN for ckeditor )

Answer (score 1):

I'm having pretty much the exact same issue. I found this link which is basically the same thing (I believe).

[How to prevent an iframe from reloading when moving it in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434230/how-to-prevent-an-iframe-from-reloading-when-moving-it-in-the-dom)