# CKEDITOR Not Displaying Content and becomes uneditable after Sorting using Jquery UI Sortable

Tags: ckeditor, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to reorder my list items using jquery UI sortable. i have a Div(a container div which holds

several div's having class "section") and a List on right( the "li" on the list has the same name of the

Section inside my container Div )

the Container Can have a number of Div with class Section
like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section" id="section1" />
    <div class="section" id="section2" />
    <div class="section" id="section3" />
</div>
```

and each of these Div(section) can have a number of blocks
like

```
<div class="section" id="section1">

    <div class="dynamic" id="block-1" />
    <div class="dynamic" id="block-2" />
    <div class="dynamic" id="block-3" />

</div>
```

inside each block i am having  text area with CKEDITOR with it (ie : there can be multiple textarea's inside of a section DIV)
and these blocks are Sortable, i had an issue with CKEDITOR before, ie : when i sort the Blocks the CKEDITOR went uneditable and lost the Contents in it ,some How i have fixed it and its working fine now.

But the New issue is 
on my right side of this div i have an UL with li having Section Names as Text
So that on Clicking each li i will show each sections at a time (works like tab)

these li's are Sortable and on sorting these li's the section's inside my container also gets sorted accordingly.

ie: say i got 3 Sections

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section" id="section1" />
    <div class="section" id="section2" />
    <div class="section" id="section3" />
</div>
```

and li like this

```
<ul class="sortableul">
    <li class="sectionlist">My Section 1</li>
    <li class="sectionlist">My Section 2</li>
    <li class="sectionlist">My Section 3</li>
</ul>
```

each li indicates sections
 if i sort the My Section 3 and move it to the top it will be like this

```
    <li class="sectionlist">My Section 3</li>
    <li class="sectionlist">My Section 1</li>
    <li class="sectionlist">My Section 2</li>
```

and as a result the div's also gets reordered like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section" id="section3" />
    <div class="section" id="section1" />
    <div class="section" id="section2" />

</div>
```

Text area's with ckeditor inside the div (section3) is getting uneditable and no content is displayed but text area's with ckeditor inside the rest of the sections are working fine

in short the text area's inside of the Div which get **dragged** is becoming uneditable and no content is Displayed.

Don't know what's happening ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CKEditor 4 and jQuery UI sortable removes content after sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124860/ckeditor-4-and-jquery-ui-sortable-removes-content-after-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

The classic type of editor (one that's based on `iframe`) will be always lost when it's moved or detached from DOM. You will find more details about why it happens and how to deal with that in a general situation here – [CKEditor loses content when removed from DOM and added again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494039/ckeditor-loses-content-when-removed-from-dom-and-added-again/30501225#30501225).

As I explained in the other answer, you will have two options – either you'll need to reinitialise editor after user moved it or you can use the [`divarea`](http://ckeditor.com/addon/divarea) plugin.

Comment: reinitialise by means destroying the editor instance and replacing it again ? i tried this in my  **stop** event in jquery sortable                         `var ckeditorId = $('.contentContainer > div:eq(' + pos + )').find('.ckeditor').attr('id');var thisEditorInstance = CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditorId];
 if (thisEditorInstance) {                       
                        thisEditorInstance.destroy(true);
                        CKEDITOR.remove(ckeditorId);
                        CKEDITOR.replace(ckeditorId);
                    }`

Comment: pos is the index of the div

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how jQ sortable works in details so I cannot help you further. One more tip though – editor must be destroyed before it is detached from DOM. Otherwise, destroying it will be harder and you'll lose data.